# If Windows download $win_file if Mac download $mac_file

Tags: php, windows, macos, download

Hi I have here a small issue!

I have a Download button for an app, but it's for 2 platforms, Windows and Mac.
I want to automate the process and when client hits download button, I need the browser to automatically identify the OS platform.

And depending on this should be something like this: If Windows download `$win_file` if Mac download `$mac_file`

How do I do that in PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the useragent string, you get this with the following code:

```
$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

It will give you something like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2
```

You would have to check this string like so:

```
if(strpos($userAgent, "Win") !== FALSE) {
    // Execute windows code
} elseif(strpos($userAgent, "Mac") !== FALSE) {
    // Execute mac code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Google told me to take a look that this site:
http://www.danielkassner.com/2010/06/11/get-user-operating-system-with-php

```
<?php
/*
Author: Daniel Kassner
Website: http://www.danielkassner.com
*/
function getOS($userAgent) {
  // Create list of operating systems with operating system name as array key 
    $oses = array (
        'iPhone' => '(iPhone)',
        'Windows 3.11' => 'Win16',
        'Windows 95' => '(Windows 95)|(Win95)|(Windows_95)', // Use regular expressions as value to identify operating system
        'Windows 98' => '(Windows 98)|(Win98)',
        'Windows 2000' => '(Windows NT 5.0)|(Windows 2000)',
        'Windows XP' => '(Windows NT 5.1)|(Windows XP)',
        'Windows 2003' => '(Windows NT 5.2)',
        'Windows Vista' => '(Windows NT 6.0)|(Windows Vista)',
        'Windows 7' => '(Windows NT 6.1)|(Windows 7)',
        'Windows NT 4.0' => '(Windows NT 4.0)|(WinNT4.0)|(WinNT)|(Windows NT)',
        'Windows ME' => 'Windows ME',
        'Open BSD'=>'OpenBSD',
        'Sun OS'=>'SunOS',
        'Linux'=>'(Linux)|(X11)',
        'Safari' => '(Safari)',
        'Macintosh'=>'(Mac_PowerPC)|(Macintosh)',
        'QNX'=>'QNX',
        'BeOS'=>'BeOS',
        'OS/2'=>'OS/2',
        'Search Bot'=>'(nuhk)|(Googlebot)|(Yammybot)|(Openbot)|(Slurp/cat)|(msnbot)|(ia_archiver)'
    );

    foreach($oses as $os=>$pattern){ // Loop through $oses array
    // Use regular expressions to check operating system type
        if(eregi($pattern, $userAgent)) { // Check if a value in $oses array matches current user agent.
            return $os; // Operating system was matched so return $oses key
        }
    }
    return 'Unknown'; // Cannot find operating system so return Unknown
}
?>

<?php
echo getOS($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
?>
```

Should be ready to use but havent tried it.